# Typescript Interface to define type for my model

Tags: typescript

I'm new to typescript and I have interface in typescript like this:

```
interface Model{
   class : String,
   id: Number
}
```

and in my model class, I have used this interface like this:

```
class MyModel{

    model: Array<Model> = []

    pushData(val){
       model.push(val) //error happens here
    }

}
```

On compilation typescript seems to be throwing error:

```
error TS2345: Argument of type '{}' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Model'.
  Property 'class' is missing in type '{}'.
```

I have checked the value of `val` is nothing but:

```
{
  class : "test", id : 123
}
```

which is matching my interface, then why typescript throws this error?

Typescript version is 1.6.2

Comment: The error message includes the filename and line number for the error. Is it pointing at some code you have posted, or are we supposed to guess where it happens? Can you post a complete example that we can try to compile ourselves? Which version of Typescript are you using?

Comment: @DCoder: Changed the code now.

Comment: For starters, the `pushData` function should be using `this.model.push`, not plain `model.push`. Once I fix that, your code compiles without any warnings on TypeScript Playground.

Comment: I would change the signature to: `pushData(val: Model)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could it be that since you are not giving val a type it's converting to an any type which is {}

```
class MyModel{

    model: Array<Model> = []
    // try this
    pushData(val:Model){
       model.push(val) //error happens here
    }

}
```